# Failing to authenticate local player iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, game-center

I'm building a Game Center game in iOS6 and am continuously running into problems with it. The current one has me stumped - Every single time my game tries to authenticate the local player it fails. Every time it is triggering my "disable game center" function and it's driving me crazy.

```
- (void) disableGameCenter
{
    // Write something to disable gamecenter.
    // gameCenterAvailable = FALSE;
}

-(void)showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    // Pause Tasks Here
//    [[[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) authenticateLocalPlayer
{
    localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    __weak GKLocalPlayer* weakLocalPlayer = localPlayer;

    weakLocalPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error)
    {
        if (viewController != nil)
        {
            [self showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable: viewController];
        }
        else if (weakLocalPlayer.isAuthenticated)
        {
            self.localPlayer = weakLocalPlayer;
        }
        else
        {
            [self disableGameCenter];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Maybe viewController is nil

Comment: That does seem to be the case, and I have no idea why. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like if authentication has failed, that something must be set in error.  If you set a break-point on "disableGameCenter", what does "error" have in it when you print it out?

Comment: Logan, try resetting your device (powering off, then on)

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you are running the authenticate method.

Try this method instead:

```
- (void) authenticateLocalPlayer
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    [localPlayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)
        {
            NSLog(@"Authenticated");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Not Authenticated");
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: That's what I used to have, but they deprecated authenticateWithCompletionHandler in iOS6, and I've been struggling to find a workaround ever since.

Comment: I still use this method on iOS 6

Comment: I just submitted an app with this exact code and I had no problems.

Comment: It does work, but I want something that I know will continue to work.